# alcohol 120% advanced emulation settings not working on win 10

Tags: windows-10

I have installed alcohol 120% on win 10, but I am not able to check those advanced emulation settings in it.

Every time I open the right click menu in its taskbar tray icon and click any of these options:

[image]

none of them gets checked when later I reopen the same menu like this:

[image]

what is going on here? What is wrong?

Comment: same problem here,, did you find any solution or any alternative

Comment: no, so solutions so far